# C# buscar imagen por nombre a través de HttpWebRequest sin saber la extension del archivo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo 2 aplicaciones en la nube donde una es administrativa y otro un directorio donde se contactan ó se registran nuevos usuarios y entre ellos doctores. Necesito recuperar la url correcta de las imagénes de la app administrativa para publicarlo en el directorio pero aunque sé la ubicacion y nombre de las imagenes, las extensiones pueden variar dependiendo como los administrativos ó usuarios lo suban como .jpg, .png, jpeg... etc.

```
                HttpWebRequest httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Setting.AppUrl + "/ Imgs/doctores/" + doctor.UIDEmpleado.ToString() + ".jpg");
                httprequest.Method = "GET";
                bool existeimagen = false;
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();
                    doctor.ProfileURL = Setting.AppUrl + "/ Imgs/doctores/" + doctor.UIDEmpleado.ToString() + ".jpg";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    existeimagen = false;
                    doctor.ProfileURL = request.AppBaseUrl + "api/doctor/getavatar/?uidempleado=" + doctor.UIDEmpleado.ToString();
                }
```

Lo que quiero saber es algún método de busqueda ó que me traiga una lista ignorando la extension para validarlo.

Comment: El problema es otro, cuando subes archivos, se debe almacenar el nombre completo del archivo incluyendo la extensión, también la ruta de dónde está almacenado. ¿Tienes acceso a esa información?

Comment: Si, tengo acceso. El detalle es que eso es un requerimiento. No se guarda, el nombre de la imagen es la uid usuario y tengo que resolver lo de la extencion.

Comment: Por ahora lo tengo con varios try y catch de probando una y otra vez con cada una de las extenciones pero es un parche que necesito cambiar.

Comment: ¿tienes acceso al filesystem donde estan las imagenes?, si es asi puedes buscar en el directorio las imagenes que coincidan con el id del usuario, algo asi como: Directory.GetFiles(Path, Id.ToString()+'.*');

Comment: Tengo acceso a los archivos pero estan en la app administrativa, yo desde el directorio saco la url de la imagen donde se encuentra ahi Y TIENE acceso. Pero eso mismo queria hacer con HttpWebRequest con ".*" pero no me busca ningun resultado.